# awk and CSV returning only one result

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

Hi folks trying a very simple awk script to parse a simple CSV. The script runs, however I am getting only one result instead of two.

CSV file:

```
Test4|Test5|Test6
Test1|Test2|Test3
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F "|" 'NR > 0 {print $2}' UserAgents.csv
```

Actual Output:

```
Test5
```

Expected Output:

```
Test5
Test2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are on a Mac, with `CR` line endings, this can be workaround:

```
awk '{print $2}' FS='|' RS='\r'
```

Result:

```
Test5
Test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file encoding to Unix (LF) resolved the issue.